# Testing GWT Java program using Microsoft edge - Windows 10

Tags: java, gwt, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have a program that I wish to test using Microsoft Edge in Windows 10. For Chrome I use the following bat file:

```
start chrome http://localhost:8080/awardtracker_n
@set JAVA_HOME=c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
@set CATALINA_HOME=c:\Tomcat
@echo Using JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
@echo Using CATALINA_HOME: %CATALINA_HOME%
@echo Listing Tomcat folder ..
@dir %CATALINA_HOME%
@echo Listing Tomcat bin folder ..
@dir %CATALINA_HOME%\bin@echo Listing batch file ...
@dir %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina
@echo Executing batch file ...
CALL %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina run
pause
```

I found a suggestion to replace chrome with:

explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Spartan.Spartan

However, this did not work. Does anyone have an answer please?

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use plug-ins in Microsoft’s Edge browser. It only supports Flash and offers no way to install a type of browser plug-in. So there is not Java plug-in for Microsoft Edge. You can still use IE Explorer 11 in Windows 10 though.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I used "explorer.exe" and it opened Edge. Regards, Glyn